# Declaring environments with xparse

Tags: environments

I'm having trouble with the xparse package's environment creating commands. What I'd like to do in the end is write my own list environment. The toy example below shows my current problem: the list shows up, but some extra text is getting appended during the closing of the environment. I "fixed" it by using the `\newenvironment` command, but I was hoping to use the argument processing options that xparse provides.

In the cljlists.sty package:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{xparselist}{}{BEGIN!\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}END!}
\newenvironment{newlist}{BEGIN!\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}END!}
```

In the document:

```
\subparagraph*[short]{Second Sub-Paragraph}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{newlist}
\item item
\end{newlist}
\begin{xparselist}{mandatory}
\item item
\end{xparselist}
```

This outputs: (sorry the image got chopped for being new, but about like this...)

*Second Sub-Paragraph* text...text BEGIN!

- item

END!BEGIN!

- item

END! shortSecond Sub-Paragraph

I'm not sure why the arguments provided to `\subparagraph` are being used by the `blahblahblah` environment when it closes. I have redefined `\subparagraph` using xparse's `\DeclareDocumentCommand`. I don't have this problem when I declare another command using xparse, however. Have I missed something important in the documentation?

---

EDIT: here's complete minimal copy of the code which reproduces the problem, including requests from the comments.

The problem should be more apparent now that I can attach photos. The list environment I created using `xparse`, is typesetting some text immediately after the environment closes, which appears to come from the arguments I provide to the subparagraph command.

Document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{toylists}

\begin{document}
\subparagraph{title}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{newenvlist}
\item item
\end{newenvlist}
\begin{xparselist}
\item item
\end{xparselist}
\end{document}
```

Package:

```
\ProvidesPackage{toylists}[2011/03/08 xparse list example]

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\subparagraph}{s o m}{\textit{#3}}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{xparselist}{}{%
\begin{itemize}}{%
\end{itemize}}

\newenvironment{newenvlist}{%
\begin{itemize}}{%
\end{itemize}}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Possibly there's a bug in `xparse`, but to be sure I could do with a full example (starting `\documentclass` and ending `\end{doccument}`): I'm a bit lost with the description of what you've actually tried.

Comment: With your updated example, I don't really see what is up. You seem to have missed out `%` characters at the end of lines, which are used to prevent spurious spaces appearing. However, that does not just apply to `xparse`.

Comment: @Joseph: would it make sense to say "use `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` to avoid worrying about spaces" in this case ?

Comment: @Bruno: Not really. The treatment of spaces by TeX is well-known, and for creating document commands with no code component there is no reason to alter this.

Comment: @cljacobs could you explain exactly what's wrong with your example? You mention that you redefine the subparagraph command as well. Could you include that? It seems to be important. When I compile your example, LaTeX doesn't like the starred version of subparagraph, but when I get rid of the star, it works exactly as I'd expect.

Comment: @seamus I've updated the edit to include the `\subparagraph` definition. It doesn't appear to have any effect. Interestingly, I don't get any complaints/errors for a starred version, even I don't redefine the command.

Comment: @cljacobs this displays fine for me. What version of xparse do you have? Put `\listfiles` in your preamble and have a look at the log file to find out...

Comment: @cljacobs: Any chance of a full log? Your problem is 'works for me' for both @seamus and for me.

Comment: @all: sorry for the delay, been on vacation. I updated my texlive distro and the problem has disappeared. Thanks for the help narrowing down the issues. I've voted up the previous comments, since there aren't any actual answers to accept.

Comment: @Joseph: I've reproduce the problem with TeX Live 2009. As cljacobs writes in his last comment, an update solved his problem, so obviously there was a bug in the older version. Shall we close this as "too localized" now?

Comment: @Hendrik: Sounds about right - bugs which are already fixed seem to fit the bill to me!